# powershell Fibonacci sequence stops early

Tags: powershell

when i enter 55 i want the function to print the fibonacci sequence 55 times but the sequence stops at 55

```
function Get-Fibonacci ($n) {
    $current = 0 ; 
    $previous = 1; 
    while ($current -lt $n) { 
        $current; 
        $current,$previous = ($current+$previous),$current
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function Get-Fibonacci ($n) {
    $current = 0 ; 
    $previous = 1; 
    for ($i=0; $i -lt $n; $i++) {
        $current; 
        $current,$previous = ($current+$previous),$current
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer which doesn't rewrite using a for loop:

```
function Get-Fibonacci ($n) {
    $current = 0 ; 
    $previous = 1; 
    $position=0
    while ($position -lt $n) { 
        $position++
        '{0} : {1}' -f $position,$current
        $current,$previous = ($current+$previous),$current
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i split the last line so $current and $previous and the function stills works the same?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  The use of $current and $previous are unchanged (other than now you're not testing whether the $current is greater than $n).

Comment: $current,$previous = ($current+$previous),$current                                                                     .                                                                                                                                                 anyway to split this function with two separate line for each

Comment: You would need to introduce a 3rd variable.  Using multple-valued assignment like this is a bit confusing, but takes a single statement rather than several.

Comment: $next=$current+$previous
        $previous=$current
        $Current=$next